# Android NSFileProviderExtension - like extension

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, nsfilemanager

I have to build an app for both android and ios. Among other things, the app provides cloud storage. Now, for ios I have implemented NSFileProviderExtension without providing a ui (basically letting the system handle it), and I can access and manage the cloud by entering the files app, selecting my app and then doing whatever needs to be done.

Now, I searched far and wide for an equivalent for this on android. I have a samsung phone, and when I enter the files app, under the cloud section I can see samsung cloud drive, google drive etc. , and I can manage files there just like I can in my app. But I have no idea what kind of provider I need to implement to achieve this. I have implemented DocumentsProvider, as it seemed to be the most likely candidate, but that doesn't appear in the files app.

Comment: Android doesn't have a "files app". Your Samsung phone might, and that app will do what whatever Samsung wants it to do. With respect to your `DocumentsProvider`, from a scrap app, start an `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` `Intent` and see if your provider shows up in the Storage Access Framework UI. If it does, then Samsung simply does not support arbitrary document providers. If it does not, then perhaps there is a problem with your `DocumentsProvider` implementation.

Comment: my app does appear in ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, just not int the files app

Comment: Then that's a limitation of Samsung's app, I guess. Perhaps they hardcoded support for a few cloud options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. My document provider is available in the stock Google "Files" file manager, and all non Samsung apps showing the system file picker but not in "My Files" on Samsung Galaxy phones.

The easiest way to check if your Document Manager working is to attach a file to Gmail (surely on an Android device with your provider installed).

So, hey Samsung! We need you adhering to the Android SAF too a.s.a.p.!